# Find principal point with given camera data and the corresponding point in the image

Tags: java, opencv, math

[image]

[image]

Using the first image, I want to first calculate the principal point and then find the point Z in the image.  For this I have given the calibration data. Does anyone have an idea how this works?
I use opencv and java for this, if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: according to your intrinsics, the principal point is: (956,347.5)

Comment: and how did you calculate this?

Comment: it is the last column of your intrinsics matrix

Comment: That is the right answer. Thank you!